# Are these sentences idiomatic

Tags: past-tense

I had forgotten a lot of what I learned about music, but it's all coming back to me now.

I forgot a lot of what I learned about music, but it's all coming back to me now.

Are both sentences idiomatic , I don't think past perfect is necessary here because of the second part of the sentence (if it is all coming back, the forgetting  is obviously finished)

Comment: The forgetting is finished in both cases. Personally, I find the first more idiomatic.

Comment: Why  is the first one more idiomatic  .the second one is not false isn't it

Comment: Presumably the speaker has recently started to study music again after a long gap, so they mean "When I took up music again, I found that **I had forgotten** a lot of what I learned when I was young".

Comment: but can  I write. I forgot a lot  of what I  learned when I was young , so it was difficult to take up music again but now.......

Comment: You asked me why I had said I found the past perfect _more_ idiomatic, so I explained why. I didn't say that using the past tense was wrong.

Comment: I forgot to copy you the message yesterday, but then your phone call reminded me to do it .   Is it better if I write had forgotten

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134013/discussion-between-user5577-and-kate-bunting).